# Java saving dom to file -> file is opened by another process after program ends

Tags: java, xml, dom

Using this method to save dom as xml, you apparently can't modify the file again in any editor (Notepad++ etc) because it keeps telling you that "This file is opened by another process"

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(_doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(_docPath);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Is there any solution or work around?

(I'm developing in Netbeans on Windows 8)

**!SOLUTION!**
Changing file location helps, if your Win account doesn't have sufficient permisions to write/edit file at current location. Sadly editor only responded as "File is being used by another process", rather then "Insuffiecient permisions" or w/e

Comment: Make sure you close the OutputStream your using in your StreamResult

Comment: That's a good point, but doesn't fix the problem. I noticed that same problem happens, when I write fole from official java oracle tutorial. So maybe it's somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify a file when it is already opened. 
Java can only clear up the heap memory.
You might need some way to close the stream